# Escaping partial regex pattern

Tags: regex

I search to built a pattern composed by some fixed parts and a variable (in reality Business Unit name). In fact, there is high chance that the variable contains some specific regex characters which can be recognize as regex control ones (i.e + or *).

Is there any regex tag that notice that a pattern subpart should be considered only as text, and ignore specific char meaning?

some kind of :

```
regex_fixed_part [escape]business + unit[/espace] regex_fixed_part
```

here, **business + unit** will be replaced in the parser by **business \+ unit**

Obviously, I could escape manually all regex char, but I search a more tidy method.

Thanks

Comment: I rather prefer to be language independant.
I'm in C# and for this purpose, I could use the Regex.Escape method. but I wanted to have this capacity directly in the regex pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many regex flavors have a utility method that automatically escapes meta characters. Java does this using `Pattern.quote(String)` and PHP has a similar function: `preg_quote(string)`. Many PCRE implementations also support the `\Q` and `\E` escape sequences. `\Q` will let the regex engine interpret all characters after it as plain literals until the next `\E`.

Example:

```
a\Q+*\Eb+
```

will match the string `a+*bbb`.

Comment: it was exactly what I was searching for (too bad I did not found it by myself), unfortunately, seems not be recognize in C# |
ArgumentException : Unrecognized escape sequence \Q.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. According http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html, only the JGsoft engine, Perl, PHP and Java support `\Q..\E`. Looks like you will need Regex.Escape (as you yourself already mentioned).

Comment: @camous - this isn't supported by .net according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html . Presumably, you'll have to build the string anyway, so `Regex.Escape` doesn't complicate it too much.

Comment: Yes finaly I use Regex.Escape for this purpose. will be ok but a bit disapointed of this lacking functionnality. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What language?

In python:

```
import re
regex_fixed = re.escape("business + unit")
```

In php, use `preg_quote()`

Comment: in PHP, preg_quote() should be used

Comment: No, in PHP you should use `preg_quote`. `addslashes` is used for escape strings used in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, use `Pattern.quote()` or `"\\Qprotected part\\E"` if you want to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[[\]\^\-\\\/?*+$().|]` with `\$&` (backslash followed by `$&`, the matched string) with the global flag on.